# Integrating resultant columns from function to main query

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-defined-functions, postgresql-8.3

I have created a function that returned a table with one row and three columns.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_event_deposit_values(INTEGER, date, date);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_event_deposit_values(event_id INTEGER, start_date date, end_date date)
RETURNS TABLE (carried_over INTEGER, current_month INTEGER, deposit INTEGER)
AS $$
DECLARE status INTEGER;
BEGIN
    carried_over := 0;
    current_month := 0;
    deposit := 0;

    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT carried_over, current_month, deposit;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Run a simple query in pgAdmin.

 `select * FROM get_event_deposit_values(20170913, '1999/01/01', '2018/05/11');`

It returns three columns with one row.


Then, run a query in conjunction with main query (saw it on a website).

`select t.id from t_events AS t, lateral get_event_deposit_values(t.id, '1999/01/01', '2018/05/11') where id = 20170913;`


An error occurred near `get_event_deposit_values(t.id`. The PostgreSQL I am running is of version 8.3 which is pretty outdated. Is there any alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation on lateral subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) (in the first version, that supports it, which is 9.3, if I haven't overlooked something) state, that it was default for table functions to be lateral even without the keyword. So there might be a slight chance, that this also the case in your version.

So try what happens, if you just remove the keyword `LATERAL`.

If that doesn't work (which I'd expect) you can select each of the different columns of the function in a subquery in the column list as a work around.

```
SELECT t.id,
       (SELECT carried_over
               FROM get_event_deposit_values(t.id, '1999/01/01', '2018/05/11')) carried_over,
       (SELECT current_month
               FROM get_event_deposit_values(t.id, '1999/01/01', '2018/05/11')) current_month,
       (SELECT deposit
               FROM get_event_deposit_values(t.id, '1999/01/01', '2018/05/11')) deposit
       FROM t_events t
       WHERE t.id = 20170913;
```

(And possibly consider updating to a more recent version.)

Comment: Seems like it is the only way. Thus, I split the function into three smaller ones which return only a value rather than a table cause I think it might be more efficient.